# How to disable submit button AFTER browser has validated fields with 'required' attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, required

We are using the following jQuery to disable submit buttons in order to prevent double submissions (slow server!).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /*SENDE BTN INAKTIV STELLEN*/
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        $(this).css({'opacity':'0.5','cursor':'wait'}).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

});
```

However, how do we fire the script AFTER the browser has validated all fields with the 'required' attribute in our HTML form?

Comment: You would need an event listener that would create the disable button function after the browser has validated the fields.

Comment: How is the validation called? Ba some onSubmit handler? If so, please show this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EDIT: I found a much more elegant way to do this. Please accept this answer if it works for you.

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/*SENDE BTN INAKTIV STELLEN*/
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {

        var myform = $('#theform');

        //checks if the form is valid
        if(myform[0].checkValidity())
        {
             $(this).css({'opacity':'0.5','cursor':'wait'}).attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

});


//this is slightly awkward but it works

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/*SENDE BTN INAKTIV STELLEN*/
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var flag = true;

    $('[required]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()) 
           flag = false;
    });

    if(flag){
       $(this).css({'opacity':'0.5','cursor':'wait'}).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else
       return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. Changed your code a little to make it applicable to all forms: if($('form[0]').checkValidity())