# Prevent double submission AND allow "required" fields

Tags: javascript, html

Starting off with a simple form that requires an email address:

```
<form action="NextPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="contact[email]" required id="frmEmailA" autocomplete="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

(Non-essential features like labels and other fields have been removed for troubleshooting purposes.)

Some time ago, I was having trouble with double submission. I remember trying many different solutions, but the only one to work I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked).

So, I implemented that solution:

```
<form action="NextPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="contact[email]" required id="frmEmailA" autocomplete="email">
    <button type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This was over a month ago, and I forgot all about it until just now. The "required" attribute now doesn't do anything as `this.form.submit();` seems to override `required`.

A lot of the solutions to this problem require a lot of plugins or extra features, but is there an elegant solution?

The most elegant solution possible would be pure html, but I expect I'll need javascript also. I'd like to avoid downloading libraries or installing plugins if at all possible.

Examples:

- [Solution using angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753400/angularjs-prevent-submissions-of-form-with-required-fields)
- [Solution using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126496/how-to-disable-submit-button-after-browser-has-validated-fields-with-required)

All I want is a form that doesn't submit twice on double clicking, and honours the `required` attribute. Ideally without having to learn a new library or markup language. I wouldn't mind writing a couple of lengthy javascript functions if I needed to. Even a page that redirects to the next page wouldn't be too inelegant.

(I also know PHP and SQL, but I don't think either of them would help here.)

Is this even possible?

Comment: A down vote and no comment? I'm trying to write the best questions I can. If anyone has guidance on how to improve this one, or where the duplicates are, I would appreciate learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of disabling the button in the `onclick` attribute of the button, disable it in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form.

You need to give the submit button a name, and then you can refer to it as `this.<name>` in the `onsubmit` attribute. Or you could give it an ID, then you could use `document.getElementById("<id>")` to refer to it.

```html
<form action="NextPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.submitButton.disabled = true;">
  <input type="email" name="contact[email]" required id="frmEmailA" autocomplete="email">
  <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The reason your code needed to call `this.form.submit()` is because clicking on a disabled button doesn't trigger the default form submission. But if you put the disabling code in the `onsubmit` attribute, it only runs once the form submission process has started.

Comment: That is a VERY elegant solution indeed. I'll give it a test, and an upvote and green tick for you if it works.

Comment: Okay, an exact copy/paste from the real project: `<form action="CreateOrder.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.submitButton.disabled = true;">`

I deleted `onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true;"`

Double click still results in double submit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `name="submitButton"` to the button?

Comment: Ah, that makes a difference does it? Okay, it works now. I have no idea why, but I'm very glad it works.

Comment: In a form, all the named elements are properties of the form element. So `this.submitButton` refers to the element with `name="submitButton"`.

Comment: Oh, duh. So I could've called it anything. I get it now.

Comment: Yeah, I realized afterward that you probably thought `submitButton` was a standard property that referred to the form's submit button, the opposite of the way `this.form` refers to the button's containing form.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery fans:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```